# Can twitter bootstrap been set nesting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a sub modal in a main modal.

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Main contant

    <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
    <a href="#subModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch sub demo modal</a>

    <!-- Sub Modal -->
    <div id="subModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Sub contant
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I close the sub modal,the main modal was closed together.
Can I set the close event for every modal on one's own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have each modal nested on the parent modal. To you archive what you need, separe the modals, so each node modal will have it own close data-dissmis attribute, and when triggered it will dissmis only that modal. (And as you need to work with submodals, it will fit your needs, because even with separete html trees, the submodal will be called above the main modal, or the first one)

Heres the fiddle example ( The HTML are a bit desorganized, sory about that ):
http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/202/

```
    <div class="container">

        <h3>Modal Example</h3>

        <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
        <div>
            <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                            <a href="#myModal2" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal2" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <select class="selectpicker" data-container="body">
                    <option>Mustard</option>
                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                    <option>Relish</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

<style>
```

As i said, you going to create two modals separated, and each one will have its own data-dismiss button, and when them get called, they will just close that specific modal, and as you can see in my example they work as submodals.